# Unable to reach host from outside network, can from same subnet

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I have two nginx acting as web proxy servers, both Ubuntu 18.04.4 fully updated. They're in failover with *keepalived* so if one dies the other takes over. They are in a DMZ network, and forward requests to several webservers in a different subnet. I cannot access them directly from company LAN, I have to proxy from another computer in the webservers network.

I'm experiencing something I cannot figure out: the *master* node sometimes doesn't respond anymore to web requests. I cannot ssh anymore from the webservers subnet, but if I login to the slave twin and ssh to it works immediately. Server load very low, everything appears normal. As soon as I stop `keepalived` (and web traffic is routed on the slave, via virtual IP) everything returns to normal and I can ssh from LAN.

I added TCP connection monitoring in Zabbix but the proxy is in the webservers net so was unable to connect during downtime. Connections appeared normal just before the breakout.

While writing I see in Zabbix it has reported another blackout, even tough connections are still routed on the slave proxy, so it's unlikely the problem is a connection exhaustion. I wasn't able to connect from slave during this time.

Both servers are virtual machines hosted in an outsourcing managed environment, so I don't know the virtualization details.

If anyone knows where I can look at to see what the problem could be... Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being some funny sysadmin which assigned master's IP to another device in the DMZ